# How to create customer Observer Event using EventConvertible in RxSwift?

Tags: rx-swift, rx-cocoa

For example in the following code the default ObserverType has an event onError where Swift.Error object can be passed. How can I create custom ObserverType / Event so that I'll be able to supply an object of a custom class.

```
class LoginService: LoginServiceProtocol {
func signIn(with credentials: Credentials) -> Observable<User> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
        /*
         Networking logic here.
        */
        observer.onNext(User()) // Simulation of successful user authentication.
        observer.onError(<#T##error: Error##Error#>) // want to user custom class object instead of Swift.Error object here
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it is to have the custom class object conform to the `Swift.Error` protocol.

```
class MyCustomClassObject: Error {
    // your custom stuff here
}
```